# Delete mulitple pointers in a method of another class

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I am editing some code of an open source game and normally the code doesn't directly access the player or creature class; however its parameter `Cylinder` is at the top of the food chain when it comes to everything.

My question is should I be deleting all these pointers or setting them to `NULL` after I am done with them?

Here is the code I've written; it works fine but I don't want to crash the server over an issue such as a dangling pointer (still a bit new to C++).

```
bool Game::removeMoney(Cylinder* cylinder, uint64_t money, uint32_t flags /*= 0*/)
{
    if (cylinder == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    if (money == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (Creature *creature = cylinder->getCreature()) {
        if (Player *player = creature->getPlayer()) {
            uint64_t cash = player->getBankBalance();
            if (cash < money) {
                return false;
            }
            player->setBankBalance(cash - money);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void Game::addMoney(Cylinder* cylinder, uint64_t money, uint32_t flags /*= 0*/)
{
    if (Creature *creature = cylinder->getCreature()) {
        if (Player *player = creature->getPlayer()) {
                player->setBankBalance(player->getBankBalance() + money);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `new` (memory allocation), why should there be any `delete` (memory deallocation)? BTW, a pointer is not deleted, a block of memory whose start address is given by a pointer may be deleted. But that memory block may be deleted only if it has been allocated dynamically.

Comment: Well what about setting it to null?

Comment: Or dereferencing the pointer, basically I just want to know if I am doing it the right way.

Comment: What do you mean "what about setting it to null"???  You are not setting any pointer to null in the code that you have posted.

Comment: The variable declarations inside the if` statements are wrong though (as far as I'm aware of, unless there's some some new syntax in C++ whatever). Declare those variables outside (and before) those `if` statements.

Comment: @barakmanos: You are wrong.  That syntax is definitely in C++11, and may well be in C++03.  It's an extension of `for (int i = 0;...)` but the test is that the variable when converted to bool is true.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Please read what's in the parenthesis.

Comment: @barakmanos this is the correct syntax and yes it is in C++11, maybe you need to update your compiler?

Comment: @barakmanos:  I actually wrote my comment thinking you had used the phrase "if I'm not wrong" - which (if true) would have made my wording direct without being rude.  As it is, please accept my apologies.

Comment: @MartinBonner: No worries... I thought I'd mention that to you, by emphasizing the "as far as I'm aware of" part, which meant I could be "unaware of" but not "wrong"... Then I realized it would make me a kind of a nit-picker... so your apology is accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (and unless the documentation says otherwise), don't `delete` objects if you are passed a pointer.  Assume that you are not being given ownership of the object.

Modern C++ helps you avoid needing to know whether you are being given ownership: you may be given a `std::shared_ptr<Cylinder>` or a `std::unique_ptr<Cylinder>` - either way, deletion is handled for you when the smart pointer goes out of scope.  But often, you have to work with a library that doesn't give you such reassurance.

There's no need to null out any pointers used within a small scope (e.g. a function).  If you keep pointer variables around for longer (in a member variable, perhaps), then it may help prevent accidents if you do so.  As C++ is not a garbage-collected language, there's no benefit from nulling pointers that are about to go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is only required if there is a call to `new` when you obtain the `Cylinder` object from the game. There probably isn't, but you need to check the code.

Setting to `NULL` is something that you do if the object pointed to has been (or is at risk of getting) deleted. This is **only** to ensure that the invalid pointer cannot be accidentally used some time later.